# How do I print out a Christmas tree with SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Well yes, this is a non-serious question, but after the 2020 many of us have had, it was time for a little levity. Enjoy...

Answer (score 22):

Running the following in xterm or a Windows 10 command window will print the tree, with lights randomly scattered and of course in lovely full color.

Happy holidays everyone!

```
set lines 350 pagesize 0
clear screen
select replace(replace(replace(r,'X',chr(27)||'[42m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(32)||'m'||'X'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
    'T',chr(27)||'[43m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(33)||'m'||'T'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
    '@',chr(27)||'[33m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(31)||'m'||'@'||chr(27)||'[0m')
from ( select lpad(' ',20-e-i)|| case when dbms_random.value < 0.3 then substr(s,1,e*2-3+i*2) 
       else substr(substr(s,1,dbms_random.value(1,e*2-3+i*2-1))||'@'||s,1,e*2-3+i*2) end r
from ( select rpad('X',40,'X') s,rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ) , 
( select level i, level+2 hop from dual connect by level <= 4 ) , lateral
( select level e from dual connect by level <= hop ) union all select lpad(' ',17)||substr(t,1,3)
from ( select rpad('X',40,'X') s,rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ) connect by level <= 5 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code to draw the Christmas tree with MSSQL

```
DECLARE @g TABLE (g GEOMETRY, ID INT IDENTITY(1,1));



-- Adjust Color

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 29 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

-- Build Christmas Tree

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('POLYGON((0 0,900 0,450 400, 0 0 ))' as geometry).STUnion(CAST('POLYGON((80 330,820 330,450 640,80 330 ))' as geometry)).STUnion(CAST('POLYGON((210 590,690 590,450 800, 210 590 ))' as geometry)));

-- Adjust Color

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 294 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

-- Build a Star

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('POLYGON ((450 910, 465.716 861.631, 516.574 861.631, 475.429 831.738, 491.145 783.369, 450 813.262, 408.855 783.369, 424.571 831.738, 383.426 861.631, 434.284 861.631, 450 910))' as geometry));

-- Build Colored Balls

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 2 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (80 290, 110 320, 140 290, 110 260, 80 290))' as geometry));

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 2 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (760 290, 790 320, 820 290, 790 260, 760 290))' as geometry));

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 3 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (210 550, 240 580, 270 550, 240 520, 210 550))' as geometry));

INSERT INTO @g(g) SELECT TOP 46 CAST('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.0000001, 0.0000001 0.0000001, 0 0))' as geometry) FROM sys.messages;

INSERT INTO @g(g) VALUES (CAST('CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (630 550, 660 580, 690 550, 660 520, 630 550))' as geometry));



SELECT g FROM @g ORDER BY ID;

GO
```

**OUTPUT in Spatial Results**

[image]

In this exercise I've used the following Spatial Data  and a method:

`POLYGON - 2-Dimensional` surface area ("Tree", "Star", and "color adjustment" area)

`CIRCULARSTRING` - Collection of circular arc segments (Ball circles)

`CURVEPOLYGON` -  2-Dimensional surface area defined by a ring ("Colored Balls")
.STUnion - Method for unionizing two geometry instances.

Drawing has been done in following steps:

1. Adjusted a color for the Tree. I draw 29 dummy triangles to get the 30st color in SSMS palette, which is kind of Green.
2. Built three `POLYGON` - triangles and unionize them.
3. Did another color adjustment to get goldish color for the Star.
4. Built a `POLYGON` in a shape of star.
5. Built four colored circles with color adjustments before each of them.
6. Run the script.
7. Switch to `"Spatial Result"` tab in SSMS.

**Happy holidays everyone!**